# assignments operator between father and son

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator

I have the next classes.

in the `main` I have 2 kinds of assignments operator (A=A and B=B).

I'm trying to get the `main` working, so I tried:

```
class A { // assume that this class is abstract
   public:
     virtual void assignment(const A& num) = 0;
     void operator=(const A& num) { assignment(num); }
     void func() = 0; // the class is abstract
};

class B: public A {
     int i;
   public:
     void assignment(const B& num) { i = num.i; }
     B& operator=(const B& num) { i = num.i; }
     void func() { cout << "hello!\n"; }
};

int main()
    A* a1 = new B(7); //assume I have it
    A* a2 = new B(6); //assume I have it
    B b1(2);
    B b2(4);
    *a1 = *a2; // implement an assignment operator
    b1 = b2; // implement an assignment operator
}
```

but I got some errors that tell me that `B` is an abstract class and then the copy constructor doesn't work

any help appreciated!

Comment: What does "A = B" actually mean (in your case)? What's expected to happen? If the left side is of type A, and B is larger, clearly something has to "give" - like when you try to fit four packs of something in a box that can only take three packs....

Comment: I changed the topic. just implement A=A and B=B.

Comment: Uhm, `a1=a2` is a memory leak (because object pointed to by `a1` is lost) but does not constitute a copy of the actual object. Did you mean `*a1 = *a2` by any chance?

Comment: yes. sorry, I am updating my topic..

Comment: seems like `virtual void assignment(const A& num)` is not implemented is `B{}`

Comment: thank you, I know.. so how can I fix the methods and operators?

Comment: Unless your C++ class has dynamically allocated memory, or a resource that needs a specific handling for one of it's member variables, then it's better to NOT have an overloaded assignment operator. Let the compiler generate it for you.

Comment: And what should `b.assignment(a)` do?  The contract defined by the base class `A` indicates that it should work, and `void B::assignment(const B& num)` doesn't fulfill that contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I see what the problem is:

```
void assignment(const B& num) { i = num.i; }
```

should be:

```
void assignment(const A& num) { ... }
```

However, we now have a problem: `num` which is of type `A` does not have a member variable `i`. So we need to ensure that `num` is actually of class `B`. The ... part in the above now turns into:

```
B& b_num = dynamic_cast<B&>(num);
i = num.i;
```

Note however that dynamic_cast may throw an exception if you are trying to convert some other type to `B&` than `B`.